# How to build a server to broadcast real time video?

Tags: flash, video, flv, real-time, broadcast

I need to build a system to broadcast videos, just like Youtube. But the video is real-time video, which means the video are captured, converted and broadcast immediately. Is there any open source software can do this?

I really need some practical guides including the requirements (hardware and software).

Thanks in advance~

Comment: Do you require flv video, or you are able to accept Windows Media video as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Red5](http://osflash.org/red5)** is probably the more well known open source streaming server capable of live streaming.  That said, the prices of commercial live streaming servers has fallen dramatically.  It's been a while since I tinkered with Red5, but I found it an overly "immature" project.

- **[Adobe Flash Media Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Media_Server)**: This server set *the standard*.  Used to be prohibitively expensive, but is cheap these days
- **[Wowza](http://www.wowzamedia.com/)**: Java based, so it runs on just about anything.  Their support forum has tutorials and people there who will help

Both Adobe and Wowza allow limited servers (10 streams) for free.

I just recently whipped up a demonstration setup with Wowza and QuickTime Broadcaster.  Everything went really well.  I was impressed with Wowza.

If Open Source is really, really important to you, then another server you might want to check out is the **[Darwin Streaming Server](http://developer.apple.com/darwin/projects/streaming/)**, although that is not Flash video oriented.

Comment: why do you think that red5 is immature ?

Comment: (Note the disclaimer, *"it's been a while"*.) When I evaluated Red5, it was undergoing constant updates to fix bugs. Long term stability under load was an issue. Memory use was an issue. (Both those last two points are important to me because my app's requirements are demanding.) Features that exist in the commercial products (like Wowza and FMS) were not there. The developer mailing list frequently discussed massive internal changes to Red5. So, yea. A qualified immature. Feel free to prove my wrong, but even you admit it cannot do HD yet.

Answer (score 2):

[Panda - an open source solution for video uploading, encoding and streaming.](http://pandastream.com/) There are other similar question like these in SO.

1. [Streaming webcam video in Flash using MP4 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583306/streaming-webcam-video-in-flash-using-mp4-encoding)
2. [Streaming video from a live webcam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629159/streaming-video-from-a-live-webcam)
3. [Video Streaming & Flash Embedding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142898/video-streaming-flash-embedding)

and [lots more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=video+streaming)

Comment: seems Panda is great. I am also looking at Red5. Anyone who knows both of them please share your experiences, thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Red5 is free but it doesn't support HD yet